# Firebase was not reconnecting ESP8266

Tags: firebase, arduino

**I solved the problem.**
I found the error in the library Firebase.cpp => void FirebaseCall::analyzeError
You should change this code
**Before**

```
void FirebaseCall::analyzeError(char* method, int status, const std::string& path_with_auth) {
if (status != 200) {
error_ = FirebaseError(status,
std::string(method) + " " + path_with_auth +
": " + http_->errorToString(status));
}
}
```

**After**

```
void FirebaseCall::analyzeError(char* method, int status, const std::string& path_with_auth) {
if (status != 200) {
error_ = FirebaseError(status,
std::string(method) + " " + path_with_auth +
": " + http_->errorToString(status));
} else {
error_ = FirebaseError();
}
}
```

Once the internet connection is disconnected, it's wired again. When I'm wired again, firebase does not connect. So when the problem is wired again, it's not connected to firebasis again. How do I do that?

```
boolean WiFiReturns() {
    if (WiFi.localIP() == IPAddress(0, 0, 0, 0))
        return 0;

    switch (WiFi.status()) {
        case WL_NO_SHIELD: return 0;
        case WL_IDLE_STATUS: return 0;
        case WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL: return 0;
        case WL_SCAN_COMPLETED: return 1;
        case WL_CONNECTED: return 1;
        case WL_CONNECT_FAILED: return 0;
        case WL_CONNECTION_LOST: return 0;
        case WL_DISCONNECTED: return 0;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

void firebasereconnect() {
    Serial.println("Trying to reconnect");
    Firebase.begin(firebaseURl, authCode);
}

void loop() {

    if (!WiFiReturns()) { 
        WiFi.isConnected();
        digitalWrite(WIFILED, HIGH);
        firebasereconnect();
    } else { 
        digitalWrite(WIFILED, LOW);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely is, that you try to connect to firebase, as long as your connection is NOT available, which can not work. Try changing:

```
if( !WiFiReturns() )
```

to

```
if( WiFiReturns() )
```

Also, currently you would call `firebasereconnect()` every time your loop is called. You are probably missing an if statement around the reconnect. I think you meant to do this with `WiFi.isConnected()` (which is not a function of the arduino WiFi library btw). Consider something like this:

```
if ( WiFiReturns() ) { 
    if( !Firebase.isConnected() ){ // replace this with your actual logic
        digitalWrite(WIFILED, HIGH);
        firebasereconnect();
    }
} else {
```

Comment: if ( WiFiReturns() ) { 
    if( !WiFi.isConnected()){ // replace this with your actual logic
        digitalWrite(WIFILED, HIGH);
        firebasereconnect();
    }
}  I did it this way, but it's not working. He's not going to Firebase again.

Comment: What do you mean with "He's not going to Firebase again"?

Comment: Always giving this error : "Trying to reconnect". Firebase does not reconnect after the internet has been disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue yesterday.

I deleted Arduino and installed with new version.

Then, in your board manager, search "esp8266" and install 2.1.0 version.

Then, as you see in this [picture](https://www.projehocam.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nodemcu-jammer2_924x768.jpg) ,click the red side.

Go to "packages > esp8266 > hardware > esp8266 > 2.0.0 > tools > sdk > include" and open "user_interface.h".

In here, you should see "#endif" at bottom. Before it, write these lines and save:

```
typedef void (*freedom_outside_cb_t)(uint8 status); 
int wifi_register_send_pkt_freedom_cb(freedom_outside_cb_t cb);
void wifi_unregister_send_pkt_freedom_cb(void);
int wifi_send_pkt_freedom(uint8 *buf, int len, bool sys_seq);
```

Then, add [this firebase library](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino) to your Arduino folder.

Then, go to Sketch --> Include Library --> Manage Libraries. In this window, write "json" to search box. You should see "ArduinoJson by Benoit Blanchon". Downgrade its version to 5.13.2.

Send the code to your NodeMCU and enjoy.

Comment: master/src/FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual std::string FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::errorToString(int)':
/Users/..../Documents/Arduino/libraries/firebase-arduino-master/src/FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:83:11: error: 'errorToString' is not a member of 'HTTPClient'

Comment: @stakabekor change your Board on Tools menu. First, use NodeMCU 0.9. If not work, use NodeMCU 1.0